# Adding Sheets and renaming automaticaly in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a new sheet in excel and renaming by giving a numerical value with three decimal places from a text box from User from in VBA but it is not working

Text box Input: 0.000
Text box Output: 0 Only
Required Form of Sheet name is 0.000

Similarly, if:

Text box Input: 25.000
Text box Output: 25 Only
Required Form of Sheet name is 25.000

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your relevant attempt and see [reprex] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For **formatting the name of your worksheet**, you might find this useful.

```
Dim sName As String
sName = "7.5"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.name = Format(sName, "0.000")
```

Without more details (see BigBen's comment), a more complete routine isn't really possible.

Comment: Very happy for your resposnse  but  this is not the requried solution , I am facing  after entering a number or numerical vlue in a textbox of a user form in VBA  like 0.000 it is becomes 0 and 25.000 as 25 similalrly 25.520 as 25.52 only    But reqried is 0.000 as 0.000 and 25.000 as 25.000 not  as 0 and 25 please help in this regard

Comment: In the original post, you wanted to name your worksheets with 3 decimal places. That's what the example above does.

Comment: If you want the value of the textbox to be 3 decimal places, then you can use the "Format" function at any time to bring about that result.